# import: com.google.analytics.tracking.android.Transaction cannot be resolved

Tags: android, google-analytics, e-commerce, tracking

I'm trying to use the Transaction class in my application but the import cannot be resolved, the EasyTracker is working fine. My import is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation has been Changed. Follow the link below

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/ecommerce